# Is there any depiction of Christianity within the original story tellings of Snow White or was it an addition of the 2012 movie?

Tags: religion, snow-white-and-the-huntsman

Within the movie *Snow White and the Huntsman* (2012), Snow White recites the Lord's Prayer, which comes from the Bible's New Testament.

Is there any depiction of Christianity within the original story tellings of Snow White, or was this only a cinematic addition?

Comment: Even if the fairy tale does not directly address Christianity, it can be assumed from the setting (early modern Germany).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](https://www.pitt.edu/~dash/type0709.html#snowwhite) is a page with several versions of *Snow White* and related stories, including modern translations of two different Grimm Brothers' versions (which are probably the direct source of most modern adaptations).

Several of the stories have incidental religious references. However, nothing as specific as the Lord's Prayer is ever mentioned.

Comment: Consider that a movie contains far more dialogue than a fairy tale would, and a line like "She remained lying in it, entrusted herself to God, and fell asleep." could turn into her saying the Lord's Prayer. There are many mentions in the original calling the evil queen the "godless queen".